# Error correction code in $F_8$ correcting $n$ errors

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory, information-theory

Suppose we're working with $F_8=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and each of message has length of $n$. Is it possible to construct an error correction code such that it corrects $n$ errors, and each error is off by $\pm1$?

For example, if the original message is $666$, the corrupted version can be $555, 556, 557, 565, \cdots, 777$.

I'm totally new to the topic of error correction codes and have no clue how to proceed. Can you guys shed some light on it?

Comment: What does $F_8$ mean?

Comment: @mathreadler It means finite field. See my update.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the example is 3 3-bit numbers?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, each digit is a 3-bit number.

Comment: Exactly how is this set of numbers a finite field? See the second section of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) to see what $\Bbb{F}_8$ looks like. The elements can be represented by 3 bits, but it is a stretch to think that their arithmetic has much to do with that of integers. For example addition in $\Bbb{F}_8$ is the bitwise XOR. Anyway, look for Lee metric codes. I'm not sure if you find anything very well suited, for that $n$ is a huge Lee distance in comparison.

Answer (score 4):

A *doubly-extended* $[9,3]$ Reed-Solomon code over the field of
8 elements can correct $3$ errors anywhere in the $9$ symbols of a codeword even if the error values
are not confined to being $\pm 1$ as you need them, or the errors are
in the information symbols, or the extra (parity check) symbols, or scattered between the information and the parity check symbols. But,
there must be no more than three errors in the nine codeword symbols.

With errors restricted to being $\pm 1$, one might be able to do better
(e.g. reduce the codeword length to $8$ or perhaps even less), but the
distance structure that you have (if a 6 is transmitted, the only
possible received symbols are 5, 6, 7) does not match the distance 
structure of the field (unless you use something like Gray coding) so
that binary codes can be used.

Comment: But will finding and correcting 3 bits be enough? Minus or plus 1 changes several bits. Sometimes 1 sometimes 2 and sometimes all 3 bits.

Comment: @mathreadler: Gray coding takes care of that. Then $\pm1$ always changes just a single bit.

Comment: Ah, now I see. That is a nice construction.